# Search and Replace URL in database?

Tags: database, 9

I need to move a Drupal 9 website to a different server and a lot of links have the old server URL. Normally for Word Press I use this tool - https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB https://interconnectit.com/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

You upload that to the server and it runs a script to search for your string and replace it with the new string.

I tried to do a regular search and replace in VS Code with -

Search //old.url.com
Replace with //new.url.com

It found all the //old.url.com but after I imported the database there are still some links that do not redirect to the new url, one of these is /user. If I go to new.url.com/user it redirects to old.url.com/user

Is there a way to do a search and replace on the database to replace the old URL?

Comment: /user redirects to different internal routes depending on the logged-in state. Routes are not site specific and a cache clear should remove any cached redirects.

Comment: How can I clear the cache if I can't log in?

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/prevent-cache-clear.html

Comment: Don't replace the old URLs by new absolute ones, replace them by relative URLs and you won't have to go through this again.

Comment: Have you looked into [Pathologic](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic)? See this documentation: https://www.drupal.org/node/257026

Comment: Also, most developers probably clear the cache from a Bash console using Drush: `drush cache:rebuild` or `drush cr` for short.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HeidiSQL utility
Select search -> Replace text ...

[image]